# Quantum State Tomography with Machine Learning

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

So, I am new to this area. I know a little bit on Machine Learning and Neural Networks and I'm a Physics student and recently I started studying Quantum Information Theory.

I found some papers and some master thesis on Arxiv and Universities sites and there are some people studying how to apply Machine Learning techniques to the problem of Quantum State Tomography. The results seems promising and they are all very interesting, which led me to study this field for my master thesis in the near future.

But I am stuck in the simplest problem that is possible to play with: how to learn the state of a **single qubit**. Yes, it is not very interesting but since I am starting in the field and studying all by myself, I decided to start with the very basic and my problem is how to join what I know from neural networks (basically, image recognition and Udacity exercises) and from Quantum Information Theory.

My problem: I have a simulated dataset of 10k measures on a state like $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are adjusted in such a way that the measures gives 70/30 of measuring 0 and 1.

The projectors are $P_0 = |0\rangle\langle0|$ and $P_1 = |1\rangle\langle1|$

Now, with the data I am not sure on how to feed it to a neural network (working with images and all that stuff is easier, but the problem o QST has its nuances). I believe I will figure it out in some way, but a good push to start will be a huge help. There is a bunch of papers on the subject, but it does not seem to have really interesting and good basic references like page courses or textbooks for someone who is starting.

This is a good reference: https://github.com/quantshah/qst-cgan

But I need something that is more... basic.

Thus the simplest question: does someone know some reference or where to start? A code example on basic quantum state tomography with one or two qubits?

Comment: it's not very clear what exactly you're asking. I'd suggest making the post more concise and focused on the question. It seems like you're just looking for references on quantum state tomography. But then you talk about ML applied to it in the title and the beginning of the post, so which is it? Please keep in mind that SE works best when a single laser-focused question is asked on each post. You can open different posts to ask different questions. See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could also try asking at the quantum computing stack exchange: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's nothing quantum about this question -- in essence, you have a random coin with 70/30 outcome, and you want to machine-learn the coin distribution.